# Nodejs Nodemailer not sending e-mail

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using `nodemailer` to send email validations with no success, I get no errors when sending the e-mail, it actually says the e-mail was sent but I recieve nothing.

I tried sending e-mails using this e-mail (with gmail integration) and it works fine.

This is my config

```js
import Mailer from "nodemailer";

async function sendEmail(emailData) {
    const SMTP = process.env.EMAIL_SMTP;

    const SENDER = Mailer.createTransport({
        host: SMTP, 
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_SENDER,
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_SENDER_PASSWORD
        },
        tls: {
            ignoreTLS: true
        }
    });

    const RECEIVER = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_SENDER,
        to: emailData.to,
        subject: emailData.subject,
        text: emailData.text,
    };

    SENDER.sendMail(RECEIVER, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("E-mail sent"); // E-mail sent is fired at console
        }
    });

    await SENDER.verify(function (err, success) {
        console.log({ err, success }); // {err: null, success: true}
    })
}
```

I'm trying to send this using local env, does this work locally or the SMTP should match my domain?

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: I have, no spams

Comment: Can you post a log of the emailData object?

Comment: What SMTP are you using?

Comment: Im using mail.leobezr.com.br, my website SMTP